# Translating an equation to polynomial expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I came across this equation:

$T(0) + {1}^2 + {2}^2 + {3}^3 + ... + {(n-2)}^2 + {(n-1)}^2 + {n}^2 $

And it is written in the book that it can be express as polynomial expression as

$a{(n)}^2 + b{(n)}^1 + e$

I will like to understand how did the equation derived into the polynomial expression. No matter how I see it, the polynomial expression does not match the equation at all.

Please go easy on me as I am weak in math and I am starting on it again after many years of inactivity. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) before?

Comment: Are you sure about the question statement ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe $a(n), b(n)$ are supposed to be polynomials?

Comment: @user1001001: that would not make much sense. The searched polynomial is cubic, which cannot be achieved by the first term. That would be a paranoid question. The use of the letter $e$ also seems dubious.

Comment: Is $3^3$ instead supposed to be $3^2$?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Call $S_n$ the sum of $n$ terms, you see that

$$S_n-S_{n-1}=n^2.$$

But

$$an^2+bn+e-a(n-1)^2-b(n-1)-e=2an-a+b$$ which is only linear in $n$.